# MySQL SELECT from json only values that are not 0.00

Tags: mysql, json

I have table prices:

```
+----+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------
| id | reseller | price                                                    |                                              
+----+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------
| 20 |        1 | {"1": "4.00", "2": "5.00", "3": "3.00", "4": "2.00", "5": "1.00", "18": "0.00", "28": "0.00"} |
| 21 |        6 | {"1": "0.00", "2": "0.00", "3": "0.00", "4": "0.00", "5": "0.00", "18": "1.00", "28": "0.00"} |
| 22 |        2 | {"1": "0.00", "2": "0.00", "3": "0.00", "4": "0.00", "5": "0.00", "18": "0.00", "28": "0.00"} |
+----+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

And need to get only values that are not 0.00 (to show in ma form only values that have defined price)...so i need to get this from output:

```
 +----+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------
| id | reseller | price                                                     |                                              
+----+----------+------------------------------------------------------------
| 20 |        1 | {"1": "4.00", "2": "5.00", "3": "3.00", "4": "2.00", "5": "1.00"}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I try only using this:

```
SELECT id, JSON_EXTRACT(price, '$.1') FROM prices WHERE reseller=1;
```

to try to get first index value witch is 4.00 but i im getting error:

```
ERROR 3143 (42000): Invalid JSON path expression. The error is around character position 3.

What sql query i need to do to show only values that have defined price and value is not 0.00?
```

Comment: I don't think you can query the values and do a comparison directly. You may be able to a subselect to return all of the values, and then select those with a value > "0.00". However, it would be better to do this in the calling script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `JSON_EXTRACT(price, '$."1"')` and you able to run that query without the error, but I agre with Sloan, I don't sure if you can select ONLY the json values diferent to "0.00" in a single simple query.
This is your query fixed:

```
SELECT id, reseller, JSON_EXTRACT(price, '$."1"') AS price FROM prices WHERE reseller=1;
+----+----------+---------------------------
| id | reseller | price                    |                                              
+----+----------+---------------------------
| 20 |        1 | "4.00"                   |
--------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks...i see where i have done wrong..i forget to include in '$.' value "1" with double quotes...simple error but hard to find it..thanks..